# Can you spare Undyne the Undying during a genocide run

Tags: undertale

I was doing a [Genocide Run](http://undertale.wikia.com/wiki/Genocide_Route), but I changed my mind and don't want to reset my save file.

Is it possible to spare Undyne the Undying during a Genocide Run?

Answer (score 8):

You can't spare Undyne the Undying, but you can spare monster kid, which ends the genocide run, places you back on the path to a neutral ending, and gives you the normal Undyne fight in 2 rooms.

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: No.
Long Answer: No, it is not possible to spare a genocide exclusive boss. Pressing [[X MERCY]] and SPARE multiple times won't progress Undyne the Undying's fight ANY further, due to the fact that she's a genocide exclusive boss. She's protecting all of the underground never giving mercy. You cannot FLEE, nor [[X MERCY]]